# measure running time of a method in Android

Tags: android, audio, time

i have a method that generates an audio signal from a smartphone's speaker, i set the duration time for 1 second. i want to know if the played sound is really played for one second or not.
for that i created a playSound() method and used getTimeInMillis() method to measure the time.

the result was varying from 11 ms to 679 ms. it seemed to me that it just measures the excution time of the method not the whole running time (the time till the playSound() stops).

is there a way to measure that time in java?

```
void genTone() throws IOException{

    double instfreq=0, numerator;

    for (int i=0;i<numSample; i++ )
    {
        numerator=(double)(i)/(double)numSample;
        instfreq    =freq1+(numerator*(freq2-freq1));
        if ((i % 1000) == 0) {
            Log.e("Current Freq:", String.format("Freq is:  %f at loop %d of %d", instfreq, i, numSample));
        }
        sample[i]=Math.sin(2*Math.PI*i/(sampleRate/instfreq));

    }
    int idx = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767)); // max positive sample for signed 16 bit integers is 32767
        // in 16 bit wave PCM, first byte is the low order byte (pcm: pulse control modulation)
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);


    }
    DataOutputStream dd=new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/tessst.wav" ));       
    dd.writeBytes("RIFF");
    dd.writeInt(48000); // Final file size not known yet, write 0 
    dd.writeBytes("WAVE");
    dd.writeBytes("fmt ");
    dd.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // Sub-chunk size, 16 for PCM
    dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) 1)); // AudioFormat, 1 for PCM
    dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes( (short) myChannels));// Number of channels, 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
    dd.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sampleRate)); // Sample rate
    dd.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes( (sampleRate*myBitsPerSample*myChannels/8))); // Byte rate, SampleRate*NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
    dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) (myChannels*myBitsPerSample/8))); // Block align, NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
    dd.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes( myBitsPerSample)); // Bits per sample
    dd.writeBytes("data");
    dd.write(generatedSnd,0,numSample);
    dd.close();


void playSound(){
    AudioTrack audioTrack= null;
    try{
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);

        audioTrack.play();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

void excute() throws IOException
{
    long time=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    playSound();
    time=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()-time;
    Log.e("time", String.format(" "+time+" ms"));
}
```

Comment: Please post your implementation of `playSound()`.